# Fine-tuning Pretrained Models for Web DOM Interaction Prediction Task

Tags: predictive-modeling, transfer-learning, graph-neural-network

I am currently working on a side project that involves predicting changes to a webpage's DOM based on user interactions. The idea is to input the initial DOM state and a user interaction, and predict the subsequent DOM state.

I've been considering using some form of a neural network for this task. I have explored both Seq2Seq models (with the possibility of using pre-trained models like GPT-2 or BERT) and Graph Neural Networks (GNNs). However, I am unsure about the feasibility and effectiveness of both approaches, and how to go about fine-tuning pre-trained models if they are to be used.

For Seq2Seq, I can imagine encoding the initial DOM and the interaction as sequences, but I am unsure of how to encode the output DOM state.

For GNNs, the situation seems even more complicated. I am considering representing each unique DOM state as a node, and each interaction causing a transition between states as an edge, but I'm unsure if this would capture all the necessary information and allow for accurate predictions.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or advice on these questions:

- Are Seq2Seq or GNNs suitable for this kind of task, or would another type of model be more appropriate?
- If Seq2Seq models or GNNs are appropriate, how should I go about encoding the DOM and interactions for these models?
- Is it common and advisable to use pre-trained models for such tasks? If so, what are the practical steps to fine-tune these models for my task?

Thanks for your time and looking forward to your inputs!

Comment: My first question would be why do you want to use machine learning to predict which paths in  a DOM are impacted by a user interaction. Isn't this deterministically calculated for example when generating patches using a virtual [DOM](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom)?